How to resolve non functional hotspot on MacBook?
I have a MacBook Pro from 2023 with Ventura 13.3 OS.
I can connect to the hotspot on my iPhone without issue, but the internet is either very slow or not working at all.
When I use the hotspot from my iPhone to iPad I can get 60 mbps download.
I already tried removing the default DNS as suggested at How to fix an annoying MacOS/iPhone hotspot bug. Now when I connect to the hotspot, the internet works for about 30 seconds but then stops working again.
How can I fix my MacBook internet to work via an iPhone hotspot?
